TDDFT in VASP, missing data
I am trying to get the UV-Vis spectra from a TDDFT calculation in VASP. I am following the instructions provided by the wiki(https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Time-dependent_density-functional_theory_calculations). It claims that the dielectric information should be present in the vasprun.xml file, but I cannot seem to find the information after running the second calculation specifying AGLO=TDHF with LOPTICS=.FALSE.
Does anyone know where the dielectric information should be printed after a TDDFT run?
Thanks.

+1. Welcome to our community.

Thank you so much!
